# Trying to strip b' ' from my Numpy array's savetxt() representation

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

So I have what I feel is a very dumb problem.

I create an array from a file:

```
A1=np.loadtxt(file, dtype='a100')
```

I want to write that array after it's done processing to another file:

```
np.savetxt("Test.txt", A1, fmt=%s, delimiter=',')
```

Why is it writing out b'string'? I think I understand it's writing it out as byte but for the life of me I can't figure out how to write it out without the b''.

I know this is probably something incredibly easy I'm overlooking!

Comment: You have a bytearray.  look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-python-string

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. Is there something I can do to the format portion of savetext to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

`A1` is loaded as an array of bytestrings.  Python3 used unicode strings as default, so usually prepends them with the 'b'.  That's normal with `print`.  I'm a little surprised that it does so also during the file write.

In any case, this seems to do the trick:

```
A2=np.array([x.decode() for x in A1])
np.savetxt("Test.txt", A2, fmt='%s', delimiter=',')
```

`A2` will have a dtype like `dtype='<U100'`.

---

My test array is:

```
array([b'one.com', b'two.url', b'three.four'], dtype='|S10')
```

loaded from a simple text file:

```
one.com
two.url
three.four
```

`.decode` is a string method.  `[x.decode() for x in A1]` works for a simple 1d array of bytestrings.  If `A1` is 2d, the iteration has to be done over all elements, not just the rows.  And if `A1` is structured array, is has to be applied to the strings within the elements.

---

Another possibility is to use a converter during load, so you get an array of (unicode) strings

```
In [508]: A1=np.loadtxt('urls.txt', dtype='U',
    converters={0:lambda x:x.decode()})
In [509]: A1
Out[509]: 
array(['one.com', 'two.url', 'three.four'], dtype='<U10')
In [510]: np.savetxt('test0.txt',A1,fmt='%s')
In [511]: cat test0.txt
one.com
two.url
three.four
```

The lib that contains `loadtxt` has a couple of converter functions, `asbytes`, `asbytes_nested`, and `asstr`.  So `converters` could also be: `converters={0:np.lib.npyio.asstr}`.

`genfromtxt` handles this without `converters`:

```
 A1=np.genfromtxt('urls.txt', dtype='U')
 # array(['one.com', 'two.url', 'three.four'], dtype='<U10')
```

To understand why `savetxt` save unicode strings as we want, but appends the `b` for bytestrings, we have to look at its code.

`np.savetxt` (running on py3) is essentially:

```
fh = open(fname, 'wb')
X = np.atleast_2d(X).T
# make a 'fmt' that matches the columns of X (with delimiters)
for row in X:
    fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
```

Looking at two sample strings (str and bytestr):

```
In [617]: asbytes('%s'%tuple(['one.two']))
Out[617]: b'one.two'

In [618]: asbytes('%s'%tuple([b'one.two']))
Out[618]: b"b'one.two'"
```

Writing to a 'wb' file removes that outer layer of `b''`, leaving the inner for the bytestring.  It also explains why strings ('plain' py3 unicode) are written as 'latin1' strings to the file.

---

You could write a bytestrings array directly, without `savetxt`.  For example:

```
A0 = array([b'one.com', b'two.url', b'three.four'], dtype='|S10')
with open('test0.txt','wb') as f:
    for x in A0:
        f.write(x+b'\n')

cat test0.txt
    one.com
    two.url
    three.four
```

Unicode strings can also be written directly, producing the same file:

```
A1 = array(['one.com', 'two.url', 'three.four'], dtype='<U10')
with open('test1.txt','w') as f:
    for x in A1:
        f.write(x+'\n')
```

The default encoding for such a file is `encoding='UTF-8'`, the same as used with `'one.com'.encode()`.  The effect it is the same as what `savetxt` does:

```
with open('test1.txt','wb') as f:
    for x in A1:
        f.write(x.encode()+b'\n')
```

---

`np.char` has `.encode` and `.decode` methods, which appear to operate iteratively on the elements of an array.

Thus

```
 np.char.decode(A1)   # convert |S10 to <U10, like [x.decode() for x in A1]
 np.char.encode(A1)   # convert <U10 to |S10
```

This works with multidimensional arrays

```
 np.savetxt('testm.txt',np.char.decode(A_bytes[:,None][:,[0,0]]),
     fmt='%s',delimiter=',  ')
```

With a structured array, `np.char.decode` has to be applied individually to each of the char fields.

Comment: I tried yours and this is what I got as an error:
`'numpy.void' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: What's the dtype of `A1`?  If `x` is a `numpy.void`, I'm guessing it is an element of a structured array.  `.decode` is a `string` method.