# Numpy recarray writes byte literals tags to my csv file?

Tags: python, csv, numpy, literals

I used the following testcode

```
import numpy as np
import csv

data = np.zeros((3,),dtype=("S24,int,float"))
with open("testtest.csv", 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=',')
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

And the data in the csv file has b'' tags (byte literal tags) for the string components of the record array.
What is the proper way to handle writing to csv of these record arrays and the best way to avoid having byte literal tags in my csv file?

Comment: This looks like [open issue #4543](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4543)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are working with Python3 which uses unicode as the default string type.  byte strings then get special `b` marking.

If I generate the data with unicode instead of bytes, this works:

```
In [654]: data1 = np.zeros((3,),dtype=("U24,int,float"))
In [655]: data1['f0']='xxx'  # more interesting string field
In [656]: with open('test.csv','w') as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f,delimiter=',')
    for row in data1:
        writer.writerow(row)
In [658]: cat test.csv
xxx,0,0.0
xxx,0,0.0
xxx,0,0.0
```

`np.savetxt` does the same thing:

```
In [668]: np.savetxt('test.csv',data1,fmt='%s',delimiter=',')
In [669]: cat test.csv
xxx,0,0.0
xxx,0,0.0
xxx,0,0.0
```

The question is, can I work around this while keeping the `S24` field?  For example by opening the file as `wb`?

I explored this issue earlier in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27513196/901925
`Trying to strip b' ' from my Numpy array`

Looks like my solutions are to either `decode` the byte field, or to write to a byte file directly.  Since your array has a mix of string and numeric fields, the `decode` solution is a bit more tedious.

```
data1 = data.astype('U24,i,f') # convert bytestring field to unicode
```

---

A helper function can be used to `decode` byte strings on the fly:

```
In [147]: fn = lambda row: [j.decode() if isinstance(j,bytes) else j for j in row]
In [148]: with open('test.csv','w') as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f,delimiter=',')
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow(fn(row))
   .....:         
In [149]: cat test.csv
xxx,0,0.0
yyy,0,0.0
zzz,0,0.0
```

Comment: Another numpy byte string formatting question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32207420/numpy-string-encoding/32208336.  Other than a custom 'format' method it stil recommends `decode`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the data in all those three dtypes? Consider using the numpy.savetxt() on a numpy array of floats or integers.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html

```
data = np.zeros((3,3))
filename='foo'
np.savetxt(filename+".csv",data,fmt='%1.6e',delimiter=",")
#fmt='%1.6e' controls how the numbers are written to the text file. 
#E.g. use fmt='%d' for integers
```